# jQuery Validation - Highlighting Radio Labels

Tags: jquery, validation, label, jquery-validate

I'm trying to use jQuery validation to highlight the labels for my radio buttons only, and not the labels for my other inputs.  I have a label for my radio button set called 'type'.  I can't seem to get it to work!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#healthForm").validate({

 highlight: function(element, errorClass) {
     $(element).addClass(errorClass)
     $(element.form).find("label[for='type']")
                    .addClass("radioerror");
  },
  unhighlight: function(element, errorClass) {
     $(element).removeClass(errorClass)
     $(element.form).find("label[for='type']")
                    .removeClass("radioerror");
  },
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        }
    });
  });
```

Comment: What's not working, the class assignment or the class styling itself?

Comment: The class assignment. I think my problem is with the find("label[for='type']")  -- is this a correct method to call it?

Comment: There there multiple form? In your HTML, 'type' is assigned to the `ID` or `Name`?

Comment: It is 
<label for = "type">Type</label>
<input name="type" type="radio" id="type1" value="Type #1" class="required" />
<input name="type" type="radio" id="type2" value="Type #2" class="required" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really familiar with jQuery's validation plugin, but this one doesn't seem right:

```
$(element.form).find("label[for='type']")
```

Firstly, I think `$(element.form)` should be `$(element).closest('form')`? I could be wrong :P

Secondly, `.find("label[for='type']")` has got nothing to do with the "`element`" as any other elements in the same form will fetch the same label.

If the label is the sibling of the radio button, you might want to use [sibling()](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) directly.

Answer (score 0):

I changed your code to the following and then it works!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#healthForm").validate({
        highlight: function(element, errorClass) {

            if(element.type == 'radio') {
                $(element.form).find('[name="' + element.name + '"]').each(function(){
                    var $this = $(this);
                    $this.closest('label[for="' + $this.attr('id') + '"]').addClass(errorClass);
                });
            }

        },
        unhighlight: function(element, errorClass) {

            if(element.type == 'radio') {
                $(element.form).find('[name="' + element.name + '"]').each(function(){
                    var $this = $(this);
                    $this.closest('label[for="' + $this.attr('id') + '"]').removeClass(errorClass);
                });
            }

        },
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I don't see enough `]` in this snippet.

Comment: I guess the search is something like regex, so you don't need to close every `[`. What's more, if you closed them, the code might not work due to strict restrictions.

Comment: I don't see your snippet running properly if the closing square braces are removed. http://jsfiddle.net/2myxcbhe/ but with the closing square braces the selector works http://jsfiddle.net/2myxcbhe/1/

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I'll update my answer then.